# When I click register, it opens php file as text instead of adding values to the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I made a simple register page, but when I click on the register button, it is not adding the specified values in the myphpadmin database which i am using , instead displaying my whole php code in the browser.

This is my insertit.php code.

```
<?php

$name = $_post['name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$collegename = $_POST['collegename'];
$mobilenumber = $_post['mobilenumber'];
$emailid = $_post['emailid'];
$gender = $_post['gender'];
$category = $_post['storemp'];

if (!empty($name) || !empty($password) || !empty($collegename) ||
!empty($mobilenumber) ||
!empty($emailid) || !empty($gender) || !empty($category)) {
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname = "onlinequiz";

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die('Connect error('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        $SELECT = "SELECT email From register Where email= ? Limit 1";
        $INSERT = "INSERT Into register (name, password,collegename, 
            mobilenumber,emailid, gender, category) values 
            (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email);
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
            $stmt->close();

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
            $stmt->bind_param("sssisss", $name, $password, $collegename, $mobilenumber, $emailid, $gender, $category);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "Registration Successful";
        } else {
            echo "Someone already registered using this email";
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
} else {
    echo "All field are required";
    die();
}
?>
```

and this is my register page code.

```
<html>
<style>
div
{
width:400px;
height:500px;
background color:green;
}
body
{
background-image:url("userregistration.jpg");
height:100%;
background-position:center;
}
</style>
<body>
<form action="insertit.php" method="POST">
<center><div><marquee><h1> USER REGISTRATION !! </h1></marquee> 
<hr>
<fieldset>
<legend> <b>USER DETAILS </b></legend>
<ul type="square">
<li>Name: <input type="varchar" name="name" required></li><br><br>
<li>Password: <input type="varchar" name="password" required></li><br> <br>
<li>college name: <input type="varchar" name="collegename" required></li><br><br>
<li>mobile number:  <input type="varchar" name="mobilenumber" required> </li><br><br>
<li>email address: <input type="email" name="emailid" required></li> <br><br>

gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" required>male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" required>female<br><br>
student or employee: <input type="radio" name="storemp" value="student" required>student
      <input type="radio" name="storemp" value="employee" required>employee <br>
<input type="submit">
</ul>
</fieldset></div></center>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, when I click on the register button, it opens up the php code in the browser.
I am using phpmyadmin and xampp to operate.

Note: My localhost database connection shows unsecured. I thought that might be a problem. In case if it is do let me know the solution. I am attaching a screen snip of the same.
[Screen snip of unsecured connection through xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTERK.png)

Can anyone help me out with this simple problem.

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: Few irrelevant things: 1. You do not need to close connection or statements every time. 2. You do not need `die()` at the end of the script unless there is something which comes after it.3. `!empty($name)` is redundant, did you want to check `isset($name)` instead?

Comment: How do you open your register page? Using File protocol i.e. `C:/xampp/..../register.html`?

Comment: First step is to ensure that PHP is installed and running correctly.
 This may sound hey hey, but who knows. An easy way to check is to run php -v from a command
 line and see if returns version information or any errors. From there lets know whats up

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP code is being shown in the browser, it implies that your server has not been setup to serve PHP scripts. 
Below are among few things you will need to do.

1.)First step is to ensure that PHP is installed and running correctly. This may sound hey hey, but who knows. An easy way to check is to run **php -v** from a command line and see if returns version information or any errors

2.) **Restarting your Server:** If you have alter any files prior to this event, you will need to restart your server

3.) **PHP File Extension Name** Ensure that you properly save your code as .php file extension name. Code save as .html or .txt will not be executable.

4.) Ensure that your php files resides on htdocs folder if you are using xampp Eg

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\your-php-projects.
```

5.**)Misconfiguration:** This may be the last thing to check. But if you care about it, You can also check for misconfigurations.

For example: In Apache’s httpd.conf file,
 you will need to make sure that the line Eg as case may be "**LoadModule php5_module**" 
has been uncommented and that there is no semi-colon (;) at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score -2):

Try type="text" instead of type="varchar"